# Как вы истрактовали бы постановку тестовой задачи?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, тестирование, junit

Имеется тестовое задание:

> Дан файл вида
>
> ```
> operand1;operand2;operation;result
> operand1;operand2;operation;result
> operand1;operand2;operation;result
> operand1;operand2;operation;result
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Каждая строка описывает арифметическое действие.
>
> - operand1 и operand2 - операнды, целые числа
> - operation - арифметическое действие + - / *
> - result - результат операции operation над operand1 и operand2
>
> В файле могут содержаться любые значения полей
>
> ---
>
> Требуется
>
> - Реализовать юнит (JUnit) тесты арифметических действий.
> - Каждое действие должно выглядеть в отчете как отдельный тестовый сценарий
>
> Конец задания
>
> ---

Я понимаю, как написать тесты JUnit, но не понимаю, что именно тестируется в данном случае.

Правильно ли я считаю, что нужно сначала написать код, который парсит переменные, 4 функции для разных арифметических действий, а потом проверять с помощью JUnit корректность работы функций на основании тестовых равенств в файле 
?

Прошу вас высказать свое понимание задачи.

Comment: Лучше уточнить это у того кто дал вам это задание.

Comment: Благодарю вас за полезный совет, если бы я мог это сделать, я бы не тратил ценное время посетителей сайта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы написал скрипт (хотя, если там несколько строк, то можно и ручками), который на основании исходного файла нагенерирует Java файл с тестами. То есть, на каждую строку исходного файла будет генерировать что то вида

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    int actual = operand1 operationoperand2;
    int expect = result;
    assertEquals(expect , actual);
}
```

ну м конечно несколько строк "обвязки" для всего этого, что бы модуль был "компилируемый".

В более навороченном виде я бы добалял проверку на 0 для operand2 если operation равно `/`.

**UPD**

Вот на коленке на perl сделать за минут 5, для собеседования считаю самое оно

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print '
import junit.framework.*;

public class JavaTest extends TestCase {

protected void setUp(){

}
';

my $i = 1;
while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($op1, $op2, $oper, $result) = split /;/, $line;
    print <<"ONE_TEST";
\@Test
public void test$i() {
    int actual = $op1 $oper $op2;
    int expect = $result;
    assertEquals(expect, actual);
}

ONE_TEST

$i += 1;
}

print "}\n";
```

Comment: KoVadim, благодарю вас. Дело в том, что у нас тест на java. Если вас не затруднит, поясните пожалуйста, вот эту строкуint actual = operand1 operationoperand2; Как по-вашему следует operation превратить из символа в операцию? С помощью switch и нескольких функций или с помощью некоторого аналога eval (найти аналог берусь сам) или другим способом?

Comment: Моя идея заключается в том, что пишеться скрипт/программа, которая генерирует файл, который и является готовым java классом, который потом компилируется стандартным способом и выполняется.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал 4 теста по 1 на каждую операцию (+ - / *)

Каждый тест бы выбирал из файла строки со своими операциями и проверял правильность результата.

Но конечно задача очень странная.